# Ionic build android apk : Application not installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, android-sdk-tools, ionic3

I have build a ionic app which generated .apk file on "ionic build android --prod --release" command. When I copied that .apk file in mobile, application is not installed error comes after I tap install button.

Note: I have marshmallow os.
I have latest Android studio installed.
My Android SDK tab -> SDK platforms :
Android 7.1.1(Nougat) status: Installed.

All other are unchecked and not installed!

Is this the problem that I haven't installed Android 6.0 marshmallow in Android sdk and i am trying the Android 7.1.1 Nougat build version on my 6.0 marshmallow os ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if you are alreday installed the app previously make sure it is deleted properly and then try to re intsall

Comment: @chowdary : please read my last para and see if you could help me! I dint understand which app you are preferring to.

Comment: check `targetSDK` in _platforms->android->AndroidManifest.xml_. Also what does `cordova platform version android` give?

Comment: You have to sign the APK with a keystore .

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else arriving here:

I just experienced this problem with the current version of Ionic and dependencies:

- ionic: 3.19.0
- Cordova: 7.1.0
- "cordova-android": "6.3.0",
- "ionic-angular": "3.9.2"
- @ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.5"

Signing the apk definitely worked for me. [https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/]

Comment: Page is not valid anymore

Comment: This is correct link, as @tumbone by mistake added ']' at the end of the URL.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/running

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

- Remove the android platform.
- Add android platform.
- Do the steps to generate apk file.

Answer (score 0):

these steeps worked for me you can go with it:

- remove android platform `ionic cordova platform remove android` --don't remove it manually because you need also to update `package.json` too.
- run `ionic cordova build android --prod --release`.
- repeat `APK` signing process, you can follow [the guide](https://ionicframework.com/docs/deployment/play-store#signing-an-apk).